# Не удаётся получить длинну VKUsersArray

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

`VKUsersArray` назвал `VKF`.
Знаю, что можно получить значение через `VKF.get(int)`

Например:

```
VKF.get(7).first_name
```

выводит строку с именем. Вопрос в следующем, как можно получить его длину?

Comment: длину чего? Имени?

Comment: @danilshik, нет, я имел ввиду количество этих имён в VKUsersArray.

Comment: разве у этого компонента нету метода .size()?

Comment: @danilshik, при использовании, приложение завершается.

Comment: @danilshik, в любом случае, я пришёл к цели другим путём.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён. Кому интересно:

```
for(VKApiUserFull userFull : VKF) {
                    data.add(new mainListClass(VKF.get(i).first_name + " " + VKF.get(i).last_name, "Подзаголовок1", "20:00", false));
                    i++;
                }
```